# REORG command in db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, reorganize

So I have been altering a table in QMF. After 3 alters I believe the table has gone into a pending reorg state so that I cannot alter it additionally. Am I correct in this assumption? If so what implications does this have and to get around it can I simply reorganize the table and continue altering it? If so, what does the syntax look like for reorganizing a table? I tried 
`REORG TABLE PIDJBIP.TABLE_NAME_T`
and receive the error:

> an unexpected token "PIDJBIP" was found following "REORG TABLE".
>   Expected tokens may include: "JOIN". SQL state = 42601.

I haven't gotten much help out of the IBM pages regarding this subject.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: The DB2 version is v10.1.400.767 and the platform is windows 7.

Answer (score 12):

`REORG` is not an SQL statement, so it cannot be issued using a SQL interface (such as QMF). You will need to run it using the DB2 Command Line Processor.

Alternatively, you might use the administrative stored procedure, which you *could* call via QMF:

```
call sysproc.admin_cmd('reorg table PIDJBIP.TABLE_NAME_T')
```